# Copy Rows Into New Sheet If Value Matches In Same Column In Sheet 1 & Sheet 2

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I need all rows returned into a new Sheet if there are matching values in Column G in two different sheets (Q1 DATA, Q2 DATA).

[image: This is the 1st Sheet (Q1 DATA)]

[image: This is the 2nd Sheet (Q2 DATA)]

I placed a `VLOOKUP` formula `=VLOOKUP('Q2 DATA'!D:D,'Q1 DATA'!D:D,2)` into the 3rd sheet where I want the rows returned to, but I keep getting a #REF! error.

I'm new to Excel so I'm sure my `VLOOKUP` is broken, but I can't seem to figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You Column_Index is incorrect, I guess. Use `=VLOOKUP('Q2 DATA'!D:D,'Q1 DATA'!D:D,1)`

Comment: @Mrig I made the adjustment, however, it doesn't return all the rows with values within them. I'm getting #N/A and #VALUE! errors. Perhaps I need to clarify by stating if the value row 1 in column D on sheet Q1 DATA matches to the any of the rows in column D on sheet Q2 I want it to return all the values within the row of the matches.

The reason is because if there are matching values, I want to compare the data in sheet Q1 DATA to the data in Q2 DATA to see the variances.

Comment: **To return all the values in a row**, you'll have to use VBA to accomplish this. Any sample data will be helpful.

Comment: @mrig Yes, i was thinking so. I'm new to Excel, but I know VBA is basically using coding (Visual Basics) within Excel correct? I;m not sure how to provide sample data either (I'm new to stackoverflow as well... ) Is there a best way so that it's easily digestible and usable for you?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data in `Sheet Q1` is structured something as shown in the image below:

[image]

and `Sheet Q2` is as:

[image]

Now, each row value of `Column D` in `Sheet Q2` is to be matched with `Column D` of `Sheet Q1`. If match found, copy range `E:I` from `Sheet Q1` to `Sheet Q2`.

Try this code:

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim data1WS As Worksheet, outputWS As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim myRange As Range, rFound As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Set dataWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet Q1")
    Set outputWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet Q2")

    lastRow = dataWS.Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).row
    Set myRange = Range(dataWS.Cells(2, 4), dataWS.Cells(lastRow, 4))

    For Each cel In myRange
        Set rFound = outputWS.Columns(4).Find(What:=cel.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
            Range(outputWS.Cells(cel.row, 5), outputWS.Cells(cel.row, 9)).Value = Range(dataWS.Cells(cel.row, 5), dataWS.Cells(cel.row, 9)).Value
        End If
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

This will give output in `Sheet Q2` as:

[image]